# Are external hard drives designed to be protected against electrostatic charge?

Tags: antistatic

Looking at the conditions in which external hard drives are used, do the drive makers make them with protection against electrostatic charge? Does the outer casing protect it against electrostatic charge?
When my external was shipped, it was shipped in a simple clear plastic bag and a cardboard box. So i guess it is a yes but not quite sure.

Comment: Buy a OEM/bulk package internal drive some time. It will almost certainly be shipped in a hard (but thin) plastic cover inside a plain cardboard box, hopefully with some shock-absorbing padding material but almost certainly not more than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being in an enclosure it will have as much protection against ESD as any other enclosed electronics, from your laptop to your DVD player.

The only chance of damage through ESD will be via the USB (or FireWire, Thunderbolt, E-SATA etc) port, but due to the design of these ports, it is pretty much impossible to come into contact with the data pins, making the chance of ESD damage negligible.